# git clone: GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssl

I'm trying to clone a git repository and I'm receiving following error while executing the command:

```
GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
```

My client machine is a Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls26/+bug/1111882

Comment: You can found solution here: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers/187199#187199 .

Answer (score 2):

This is Known bug as @Ivan Ternovtsiy said ,but there is workaround

Remove current GIT from your system

```
 sudo apt-get purge git
```

Download GIT deb git_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb [link](https://ftp.iitm.ac.in/linux/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb)

Execute the downloaded DEB.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in china,may be you should set proxy for git,for example

```
git config --global https.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9999'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mileage may vary, but in my case I was suspecting two factors:

- low download speed -> connection too long on big repository
- my Internet provider doesn't like long connections and closes them

So I decided to change Internet provider *and* pick a higher bandwidth. It's working fine now. I'm not sure if only changing provider *or* picking a higher bandwidth would have been enough, so you'd have to try out.

Note: I used to use [a workaround I mentioned in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378914/git-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-gnutls/54470389#54470389) which is about shallow cloning, and that made me think that shorter connections may work.