# git error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu-16.04, git-submodules

I tried `git submodule update --init --recursive`

and got following error

`error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed`

My OS is window 10 and I'm using docker for windows. `Docker` images is `ubuntu:16.04`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378914/git-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-gnutls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing openssl package, as another option could be network issue.

Comment: I have openssl package installed, and using mobile's internet through wifi-hotspot, can't fix this issue though I have same connection day before. I did reset date and time after taking cmos-battery out, because of not turning PC on, can you suggest something?

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly the same error code, but one response to [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019906/error-rpc-failed-curl-56-gnutls-recv-error-110-the-tls-connection-was-non) recommends setting large buffer sizes in the git global config settings;

```
  git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000  
  git config --global https.postBuffer 524288000
```

This worked for me to overcome a similar error as yours, trying to clone the cppcheck repo off GitHub;

```
enter code here`remote: Counting objects: 100% (325/325), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (159/159), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using Ubuntu and turns out it didn't have the openSSL package. I installed it using:

```bash
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

For me uninstalling and reinstalling git again worked for me

Remove git with `sudo apt-get purge git` but NOT with `sudo apt-get --purge git` for some reason it wont work if you do `--purge`. Now install it again by typing `sudo apt-get install git`. And then when you try your clone, it should work properly.