# Tensorflow Serving Docker Image Installation Error curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to create a docker image using the following command

```
docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .
```

But  when it runs the following command ,

```
Step 13/19 : RUN mkdir /bazel &&     cd /bazel &&     curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36" -fSsL -O https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/$BAZEL_VERSION/bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh &&     curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36" -fSsL -o /bazel/LICENSE.txt https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bazelbuild/bazel/master/LICENSE &&     chmod +x bazel-*.sh &&     ./bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh &&     cd / &&     rm -f /bazel/bazel-$BAZEL_VERSION-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
```

it shows the exception

**curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.**

it shows the following exception

Answer (score 1):

It usually would be a network issue. I remember getting such error. Also refer the given links stating that this is a network issue:

1. https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1707
2. [git error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035434/git-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-gnutls-recv-error-54-error-in-the-pull-functi)

Hope this helps!