# "error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated"

Tags: bitbucket

Dear community when I clone the project from bitbucket this error message apperas

"error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated"

Does anyone know how can I fix it ?? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try below solution may help you! if not please let me know, Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

git config --global https.postBuffer 524288000

git config --global core.compression -1
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn’t solve the problem, I have tried it

Comment: Not working for me as well, as I explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64878273).

Comment: I simply restarted the system and followed these steps and it worked. Thanks

Comment: didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to recompile git with openssl not gnults. Please refer this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529639/gnutls-recv-error-110-the-tls-connection-was-non-properly-terminated#)
It works for me in Ubuntu 18.04 & 20.04

Answer (score -1):

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/****': GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

solution：
https://stdworkflow.com/782/fatal-cannot-access-https-github-com-gnutls-recv-error-110-the-tls-connection-was-non-pr

run commands as follows：

```sh
apt-get install gnutls-bin
git config --global http.sslVerify false
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```