# git error:RPC failed,curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110)

Tags: git, ssl, gnutls

How can I solve this error when I run `git clone` on the linux git repository?

> error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

```
root# git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git ./

Cloning into '.'...
remote: Counting objects: 6111067, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (27618/27618), done.
remote: Total 6111067 (delta 73093), reused 81877 (delta 67889)
Receiving objects: 100% (6111067/6111067), 1.07 GiB | 1.53 MiB/s, done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5127316/5127316), done.
```

Comment: I have tried many times including reboot my pc, but it still failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378914/git-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-gnutls)