# How to make go get work for golang.org when behind corporate firewall

Tags: git, go, ssl-certificate, firewall, go-get

First of all, although it looks the same as the following questions

- [How to fix git error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378914/)
- [git error:RPC failed,curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813406/), and
- ["error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019906), in which Hovo Asatryan has commented *"it doesn’t solve the problem, I have tried it"*, and I've tried it too, and neither it worked for me.

it is *NOT*. as all those questions are on `git` but this is on `go get`:

```
$ go get -v -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at //golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd .; git clone -- https://go.googlesource.com/tools /path/to/Go/src/golang.org/x/tools
Cloning into '.../Go/src/golang.org/x/tools'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports: exit status 128
```

None of the solution works for me, and I believe for anyone within a typical corporate dev environment:

- We access the Internet behind corporate firewall, thus any secure https access would fail unless special treated.
- Apart from accessing public https git repos like above, https://go.googlesource.com/tools, which is more or less an one off thing, we need to accessing our in house https TFS git repos ***all the times***. Thus I cannot change the git https access method as other solution suggested.
- I tried to use `git config --global http.sslVerify false` beforehand but the problem remains exactly the same.

So the question is, how can I let `go get` to tell `git` to relax on its security check?
I think that's the only option I have but I'm all ears.

PS. `-insecure` doesn't work either:

```
$ go get -v -insecure golang.org/x/sys/unix
get "golang.org/x/sys/unix": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/sys", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/sys"} at //golang.org/x/sys/unix?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/sys/unix": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
golang.org/x/sys (download)
# cd .; git clone -- https://go.googlesource.com/sys /path/to/Go/src/golang.org/x/sys
Cloning into '/path/to/Go/src/golang.org/x/sys'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
package golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 128
```

PPS. `curl -s https://go.googlesource.com/sys` works just fine for me:

```
$ curl -s https://go.googlesource.com/sys
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>sys - Git at Google</title><link rel="stylesheet" . . .
```

Comment: This message means your corporate firewall is broken and doesn't speak TLS properly.  The TLS standard requires that a connection be correctly terminated, regardless of whether you choose to validate the certificate or not.  You'll need to use SSH instead or get your company to fix their broken TLS MITM device.

Comment: Thx. The broken TLS MITM device is **Zscaler**. I have no way to reason my company, a Windows-only-C#-shop, to fix it for my _"personal"_ problem. So the only thing I can do is to name it publicly here.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent too much time on this. F*ing ZScaller.
What finally worked for me was to switch from the WSL version of go (Ubuntu 20 go 1.13 I think) to the latest one (1.17.3)

I used a mix from the following links to achieve this, probably a better way exists:
https://gist.github.com/nikhita/432436d570b89cab172dcf2894465753
https://askubuntu.com/questions/720260/updating-golang-on-ubuntu

but just in case somebody noob as me gets here:

```
sudo apt-get purge golang*
curl -k https://dl.google.com/go/go1.17.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz --output go1.17.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf ./go1.17.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
GOPATH=~/go
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
go install package@latest
```

> success. FUZ (F U ZScaller)

Comment:  FUZ (F U ZScaller)!! I'll give it a try (at this weekend) and let you know...