# git pull failed with error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function

Tags: git

I'm trying to pull from origin which is on gitlab but when i run the command `git pull origin <branch name>`, after some time i get the following error:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 23, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
error: 2601 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

What should i do? I tried some solutions but none of them worked for me

Comment: This is some sort of network problem.  What operating system are you on?  Is there a proxy or TLS MITM device in your network?  If you're using Windows, are you using a non-default antivrus or firewall?

Comment: for clarification is this your error type ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378914/how-to-fix-git-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-gnutls)