# Git not working mint linux 20.3: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet

Tags: git, debian, linux-mint

*Originally from https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10762*

Following:

1. Boot from linuxmint-20.3-cinnamon-64bit.iso (https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=292)
2. Establish ethernet or WiFi internet connection.
3. Open terminal
4. `git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Produces the error:

```
jonathan@jonathan-pc:/$ sudo git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
Cloning into 'crates.io-index'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 420411, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1405/1405), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (658/658), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I have looked through [How to fix git error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378914/how-to-fix-git-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-gnutls) but none of these suggestions seem to have any affect.

This seems to be a bug in Mint Linux but I don't know where to report it.

---

*For now I will just switch to ubuntu*

Comment: This is likely some sort of network issue, either with your network card, Internet connection or ISP, or some sort of network device (e.g., proxy, TLS middlebox) between Git and GitHub.