# git clone GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: linux, git, bitbucket

I tried to clone my project on my linux server via git and suddenly got this error:

> GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was
>   received.

This is asked many times, but answered none.

I am using bitbucket.

Comment: as masadi zainul noticed, potential duplicate of [git clone: GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044234/git-clone-gnutls-recv-error-9-a-tls-packet-with-unexpected-length-was-recei) (proposed duplicate flag to get the proper metadata in place)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out you just need to remove git with `sudo apt-get purge git` but NOT with `sudo apt-get --purge git` for some reason it wont work if you do `--purge`. Now install it again by typing `sudo apt-get install git`. And then when you try your clone, it should work properly.

Comment: same with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044234/git-clone-gnutls-recv-error-9-a-tls-packet-with-unexpected-length-was-recei

Comment: Seems like `remove` is needed when you use `--purge`:

(from man apt-get:  remove --purge is equivalent to the purge command)

So it should be `apt-get remove --purge package`